# Use eval without threat of XSS

Tags: javascript, security, xss, eval

I was making(not now, but still I'm curious about this one) a game using HTML5 and JS, and one I wanted was that people can insert custom script, but secure.

```
function executeCustomJS(code){
 eval(code);//bad
}
```

Of course this code is very bad, because if code is something like `document.location.href='http://meatspn.com'`, then the result will become very...(...)

One solution I found is escaping(like `eval` -> `___eval___`) all keywords, and un-escape keywords in whitelist, such as 'while', 'for', 'if', 'var', 'true', 'false', ... and 'func0', 'func1', ...., which are something (like API) of the game and are secure.

For example,

```
function executeCustomJS(code){
 code = code.replace(/(Keyword RegEx)/g,'___$1___');
 /*unescape keywords in whitelist*/
 eval(code);
}
```

I haven't made RegEx and things in comment, but that's not the question.

Let's assume strings in code are not escaped, there's no function which can be made by escaping a string, and 'eval', 'window', 'document', 'alert', 'location' are NOT in the whitelist. Still some people can execute code like `while(true){}`, they can't execute any code like `document.location.href='http://meatspn.com'`.

Is this method secure? Or, is better way exists or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you expose a limited scripting language over JSON. So document a scripting engine that requires you to create a JSON object as your code.

This has the large advantage that it's impossible to inject bad code into JSON because it's just data.

So you can create some kind of declarative syntax for your scripting code. For example

```
{
    "0": {
        "Action": "move",
        "X": 10,
        "Y": -5
    },
    "1": {
        "Action": "emote",
        "type": "dance"
    }
}
```

Now what is a good design for a tiny declarative scripting language is a completely different question.

Comment: If that's supposed to be JSON, you need to treat the property names as strings. `{ "Action": ...`

Comment: Thank you! (but I'm still curious about whether my method is secure..)

Comment: @tylermwashburn it's actually an object literal. But yes JSON needs properties in strings. @JiminP it's only secure if you know more about javascript then me ;). I can see your white list parser, you've send it to me. I can find all the holes in it. Your going to watch meatspn over and over again :)

Comment: @Raynos With object literal's you can still store more then data. `x: function () { bombJapan(); }`

Comment: @tylermwashburn that's true. But you can't create an object literal containing a function through `JSON.parse`. The idea is to load JSON, the example just happened to be an object literal constrained by JSON. Maybe I should change the example to JSON :)

Answer (score 0):

Expose anything the user may wish to do as `combinators`, e.g. a sublanguage.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/caja/

> The Caja Compiler is a tool for making third party HTML, CSS and JavaScript safe to embed in your website. It enables rich interaction between the embedding page and the embedded applications. Caja uses an object-capability security model to allow for a wide range of flexible security policies, so that your website can effectively control what embedded third party code can do with user data.